# Using Lapply with the cocor function in R

Tags: r, lapply, multiple-databases

I am trying to use the cocor function in r but across levels for a variable in my data set. This is the code I use:

```
lapply(split(CD, CD$Measure.Name), function(x) cocor(~x[,3] + x[,2] | x[,3] + x[,5], data = CD))
```

- `CD` = Dataset name.
- `Measure.The name` is the Factor I am splitting on (so I want the color function to be done but by each measure, I have for that factor).

However, this is the error I get when I run that code:

> Error in cocor(~x[,3] + x[,2] | x[,3] +
>   x[,5]),  :For correlations based on dependent groups, the
>   parameter 'formula' must be a formula of the form ~a + b | a + c if
>   the two correlations are overlapping or ~a + b | c + d if the two
>   correlations are nonoverlapping.

Can someone help assist me in figuring this out?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please share a sample of your data. I think your statement should be something like `cocor(~var3 + var2 | var3 + var5, data = x)`

Comment: That is correct. Except, I want to apply the cocor function across the levels I have for my "Measure.Name" factor.

Comment: this should do that. `x` will be a subset of `CD` for each unique value of `Measure.Name`, and `cocor` will evaluate the formula using each `x` as the data

Comment: Okay! I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: It worked! Wow, I have been working on this for approximately 2 hours (thinking it was a huge error in my code I was making) and I was just using CD as my data-set instead of x. Thank you!!